# Marshalling class with enum

Tags: c#, enums, c++-cli, marshalling

I'm having issues marshalling a class with an `enum` member from c++/cli into C#, getting crashes due to read violations.

In my c++/cli project, I have this:

```
public enum ExtensionType { Primary, Secondary }
public ref class Data {
public:
    String^ Descriptor;
    ExtensionType ExtensionType;
}
```

Then I declare matching types in C#:

```
public enum ExtensionType { Primary, Secondary }
public class Data {
    public string Descriptor;
    ExtensionType ExtensionType;
}
```

Which I then try to marshal:

```
_data = (Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(dataPointer, typeof(Data));
```

At this point, the application crashes. Do I need to throw some attributes on the enum?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the types once only. You are declaring the types twice and so have two different copies of the types. You have two versions of the enum, one in the C++/CLI assembly, and one in the C#. And you have two versions of the class, one in the C++/CLI assembly, and one in the C#.

What you need to do is add the C++/CLI assembly as a reference to your C# executable. Define the types in the C++/CLI module, and use them in your C# code just as you would use any other type from a referenced assembly. Or if the dependency is the other way around, declare the types in the C# code, add the C# assembly as a reference to your C++/CLI executable.

Your use of `Marshal.PtrToStructure` is quite wrong. That is for marshalling unmanaged types, typically when using p/invoke. Here you have pure managed types and so there is no place for `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! But maybe my minimal sample was too minimal... The scenario is application hooking/injection. There is quite a lot going on in the code so it's a bit hard extracting into the question, but it works when I do not have the enum. I didn't write the original code the does the `PtrToStructure`, but it does seem to work as is (as long as the classes are identical on both sides).

Comment: I don't really see that it is fair to supply all the important details in a comment after I've taken the time to answer. In any case, my answer still stands. You need not to make duplicate types that have the same name and look the same, but are in fact distinct.

Comment: David: Sorry about that. As I'm a bit of a novice in the marshalling/interop area was a bit unsure about what parts are relevant. I'll have to try removing the duplicated types and see if that works.